# jQuery function in external file not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this code in external file "selectors.js"

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#clickHere").click(function(){
        $("#hidingthis").show();
    });
});
```

This is the relevant HTML:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="static/js/selectors.js" ></script>

<div id="hidingthis" style="display:none"> Text here </div>

<button id="clickHere"> <strong> Click here </Strong> </buton>
```

it works perfectly when put into script tags within the HTML file. Any ideas?

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: Are you sure the file `selectors.js` is correctly loaded ? check your console

Comment: The jQuery code does not work at all. When I click the div it has no affect. I'm wondering what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: yes the file is being loaded correctly.

Comment: the code looks ok, the script must being not loaded properly

Comment: put an alert in the script and see what happens

Comment: The alert is showing after clearing cache so must be a jquery issue?

Comment: Whats the URL you are running it from? i say this as your path to the selectors.js is relative....

Answer (score 0):

Try checking the Developer Tools (F12) within your browser and taking a look at the Network and Console tabs. It sounds like your script is not being properly loaded (or it is being referenced before your jQuery code is actually ready).

This could be the result of a bad path for your `selectors.js` file, which the previous suggestions should reveal (via a 404 error).

Comment: Nope, there are no errors. And I can see the selectors.js file in Dev tools. It just doesn't seem to be running though. I put a window alert in it and got nothing.

Comment: Where are your scripts currently located / referenced? Are they declared within the `<head>` section? If so, you might want to consider placing them at the bottom, just before the closing `</body>` tag. You might also consider closing your browser / windows and re-opening them in case this was a caching issue.

Comment: I closed my browser, cleared my cache. The alert that I put in the code is now showing but the jQuery is still not working. The IDs are exactly the same here as my code, i've triple checked.... (The code works within script tags in the HTML file as well?)

Comment: Although this may be trivial, your current closing tag for your `<button>` is actually `</buton>`. It may be nothing, but it's probably worth changing. Do the Dev. Tools show that your jQuery reference is loading properly from the CDN? [This example](http://jsbin.com/qewuwi/edit?html,js,output) seems to basically be your exact scenario and it works as expected. Does yours differ in any major ways?

Comment: I think I have figured it out. To an extent. The button is being created within script tags in the HTML file. When I set the ID to something else outside those said script tags, the div appears when it is clicked. Any idea why this doesn't work?

Comment: You mentioned that the `<button>` is being created within `<script>` tags, can you elaborate on this a bit more? What does your entire markup / scripts look like? It sounds like some kind of syntax error might be causing this, but looking at your entire code should clear it up.

Answer (score -1):

You should put your script tag below the content you want show. It is because your HTML is not loaded